# Mask number input for text field and default to iPad number input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, ipad

### Background

- I have a form with a field that users will enter.
- The input of the field is all numeric.
- However, the result of the field will be masked to a text input

  - e.g. a user typing "9999999" will see "9999-999"
- The field will ultimately be submitted as text.

I think the solution is to:

- Use a plugin such as [jQuery Mask](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) to do input masking
- Use the input type of "number" so that the iPad's keypad will default to a number

### Problem

- If I use the "number" input type, the masking won't work because it inserts a dash in a field reserved only for numbers.
- If I use the masking with a text field, the iPad's keypad doesn't default to a number.

Comment: i faced the same problem and am currently using jquery mask. users simply have to change to numeric keyboard on ios devices.

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
 if (!isiPad){
  $("#id").mask("99999-999");
 }
}
```